# Using paste function within colnames

Tags: r, paste

I want to use iteration to turn the entries in a list into a 2x2 matrix, and then assign the same column and row names to these tables, as well as integer values for the matrix cells.

For examples sake let's pretend this is the list with the entries whose names I want to turn into matrices:

```
cnames <- c("Honda", "Toyota", "Nissan")
```

Creating the tables themselves seem to work fine with the assign function:

```
for (i in 1:length(cnames)){
    assign(paste(cnames[i],"table",sep="_"), matrix(,nrow=2,ncol=2))
}
```

Which when I type, for instance:

```
> Honda_table
```

...returns:

```
   [,1] [,2]
[1,]  NA   NA
[2,]  NA   NA
```

But if in the original iterative function I try to assign column names, like such:

```
for (i in 1:length(cnames)){
    assign(paste(cnames[i],"table",sep="_"), matrix(,nrow=2,ncol=2))
    colnames(paste(cnames[i],"table",sep="_")) <- c("A","B")
    }
```

...I get this error instead:

```
Error : attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

I don't understand why this is coming up, since after using the original assign function, if I look up the dimensions any of the tables, such as:

```
>dim(honda_table)
```

...I get:

```
[1] 2 2
```

Which indicates it is a 2x2 dimensional object.

Moreover, I cannot assign pre-set values to the matrix cells, like so:

```
for (i in 1:length(cnames)){
    assign(paste(cnames[i],"table",sep="_"), matrix(,nrow=2,ncol=2))
    paste(cnames[i],"table",sep="_")[1,1] = 1
}
```

...without getting this error:

```
Error : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

What is going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to call `colnames` on a string instead of an object name. There are ways around this, but they're discouraged practices (as is using `assign`). Instead of your `for` loop, make a list with `lapply`.

Comment: This: `colnames(paste(cnames[i],"table",sep="_")) <- c("A","B")` is trying to set `colnames` on just one element (e.g. `"Honda"`). That should be why your dimensions are off.

Comment: @alistaire example with lapply?  I think I see what you're getting at

Comment: A tad clunky, but `setNames(lapply(cnames, function(x){matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c('A', 'B')))}), cnames)`. Alternately, `setNames(rep(list(matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c('A', 'B')))), length(cnames)), cnames)`

Comment: @desc it works outside of the for loop though, etc   `colnames(paste(cnames[2],"table",sep="_")) <- c("A","B")`

Comment: This question needs some `fortunes::fortune(236)`

Comment: @alistaire problem is I will need the iterative loop to add the values to the matrix cells from a much larger, combined matrix, etc `honda_table[1,1] = bigmatrix[i, j]`, `honda_table[1,2] = bigmatrix[i, j+1]`, etc...

Comment: That's almost certainly not the best way to do it. It's hard to say what is without more context, but there's almost always a better alternative in R, even if it's just `*apply`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure it is the best, and the most beautiful, way but seems to work:

```
for (i in 1:length(cnames)){
 tab<- matrix(,nrow=2,ncol=2)
 colnames(tab)<-  c("A","B")
 assign(paste(cnames[i],"table",sep="_"), tab)
 }
rm(tab)
```

Comment: this might work, just wondering if there was a way to do this without assign function, if not i'll credit this answer.  Can't believe I didn't think of this though.

Answer (score 1):

After much suggestion I ended up scraping the assign function and simply created a vector of tables instead